# Error with bias in backpropagation

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, bias-neuron

[image]

This is my nn.

and here is the code:

```
import numpy as np


def relu(x):

    x = np.where(x>=0,x,x*.1)
    return x

def deriv_relu(x):
    x = np.where(x>=0,1,x*.1)
    return x

def bias(x):
    e = np.ones((x.shape[0],1))
    e1 = np.hstack((e,x))
    return e1

X = np.array([[1,1],[1,0],[0,0]]) #3,2

y = np.array([[1,1,0]]).T #3,1

w0 = np.random.random((2,5)) #2,5
w1 = np.random.random((6,1)) #6,1

for i in range(4):
    l0 = X #3,2


    h1 = relu(l0.dot(w0)) #3,5
    h1_bias = bias(h1) #3,6

    l1 = relu(h1_bias.dot(w1)) #3,1

    error = y-l1 #3,1
    delta2 = error*deriv_relu(l1) #3,1

    error2 = delta2.dot(w1.T) #3,6


    delta = error2*deriv_relu(h1_bias)#3,6


    w1+=h1_bias.T.dot(delta2) #6,1
    w0+=l0.T.dot(delta) # w0 is shape 2,5, because of added bias i am dead. Any help?


for a,b in zip(l1,y):
    print(a,b)
```

The problem I am facing is, I added a bias neuron in hidden layer 1. When I start with backpropagation and matrix multiplications, I get in problem, because the dimensions are of course not aligned, which is of course of added bias. I am thinking how to overcome this issue. Is there a way I could do this within my code?

Comment: Biases are used to shift the activation function, and they are just _added_ to that function's input.

Comment: @ForceBru I added it after activation function **h1 = relu(l0.dot(w0)) #3,5 h1_bias = bias(h1) #3,6** Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you `hstack`ing in `bias`? A bias is of the same shape as `l0.dot(w0)`.

Comment: @ForceBru if I don't add bias as I do, then features with [0,0] will always be zero...

Comment: @ForceBru I solved it with l0.dot(w0)+1.. it works. Thank you.